# Angular 10. Radio button is not checked by default

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

We have the radio button group and try to make the default selection for *Female* Radio option.

```
<ng-template #genderTemplate>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label class="ari-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
        </div>
        <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
          <input formControlName="gender" type="radio" [value]="true" /> Male
          <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
          <input formControlName="gender" type="radio" [value]="false" [checked]="!gender"/> Female
          <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

It is not working. Any clue?

Comment: Please also post your code, not just the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You will have add name="gender" in html
Too in the .ts add   gender:boolean=false;

```
<ng-template #genderTemplate>
<div>
  <div>
    <label class="ari-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
  </div>
  <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
    <input formControlName="gender" type="radio" name="gender" ngModel [value]="true" /> Male
    <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
  </label>
  <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
    <input formControlName="gender" type="radio" name="gender" ngModel [value]="false" [checked]="!gender"/> Female
    <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It Can't help..

Comment: You can insert all code?

Answer (score 0):

To your HTML template, I added the name attribute to group the radio buttons together. I changed the value of male to 'male' and the value of female to 'female'. Then I set the default value for the gender formControl in Typescript to 'female', so the female button will be selected initially.

Better would be to initialize an enum for the gender types.

Therefore, your template should look something like:

```
<ng-template #genderTemplate>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label class="ari-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
    </div>
    <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
      <input
        formControlName="gender"
        type="radio"
        name="gender"
        value="male"
      />
      Male
      <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
      <input
        formControlName="gender"
        type="radio"
        name="gender"
        value="female"
      />
      Female
      <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Typescript form group:

```
form: UntypedFormGroup;
constructor(private fb: UntypedFormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        gender: ['female'],
        // all the other controls in the form
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it won't have any impact. Also, providing a name attribute makes the radio button unselectable.

Comment: did you add the default value to the form in your typescript? I tested the solution and it works..